# Почему падает postfix?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

После обновления ubuntu c 15.10 до 16.04 почему-то падает postfix, примерно через минуту после запуска.

```
May 10 14:25:19 passat postfix/master[37307]: daemon started -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
```

May 10 14:26:05 passat postfix/master[37307]: terminating on signal 15

В main.cf включен debug_level=2

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = no
biff = no
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
message_size_limit = 15728640
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mydomain = domain.ru
myhostname = domain.ru
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks, cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = zen.spamhaus.org*3 b.barracudacentral.org*2 bl.spameatingmonkey.net*2 bl.spamcop.net dnsbl.sorbs.net psbl.surriel.com bl.mailspike.net swl.spamhaus.org*-4 list.dn swl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].0*-2 list.dnswl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].1*-3 list.dnswl.org=127.[0..255].[0..255].[2..255]*-4
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 2
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $r elocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virt ual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
relayhost = relay.domain.ru:25
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname reject_invalid_helo_hostname check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unlisted_recipient check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777 permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_a uthenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unlisted_sender permit_mynetworks reject_sender_login_mismatch permit_sasl_authenticated check_sende r_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
swap_bangpath = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf proxy:mysql:/ etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

Comment: Надо логи смотреть

Comment: В логах буквально 2 строки, запуск и terminating on signal 15

Comment: Значит надо повысить debug_level. signal 15 - это SIGTERM. В общем ничего плохого. Стандартный, можно сказать, способ остановить программу. Кто-то или что-то убивает ваш постфикс. Может он сам себя. Увеличьте уровень дебага, кроме того бывает, что логи по разным файлам раскидываются.

Comment: C этим тоже проблема при попытке увеличить его больше 2      warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 277: overriding earlier entry: debug_peer_level=2

Comment: Увеличит debug_peer_level тоже что-то мешает?

Comment: Ничего кроме указанной выше ошибки это не дает. Вообще про допустимые значения этого параметра в документации ничего нет.

Comment: возможно, процесс «убивает» непосредственно linux. например, из-за ошибки out of memory (oom). ищите «хвосты» в `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` и в выводе программы `dmesg`, читающей кольцевой буфер linux-а.

Comment: Не может постфикс зациклится, вызывая оом из-за этих первых двух строк `alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases`
`alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases`?

Comment: /var/log/messages у меня нет. в syslog в момент падения postfix     May 11 09:13:25 passat postfix[53931]:  * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
May 11 09:13:27 passat systemd[1]: Started LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
May 11 09:13:27 passat systemd[1]: Reached target Mail Transport Agent.

Comment: В выводе dmesg по словам mail, postfix и Mail ничего не ищется. Попеременное комментирование двух параметров из main.cf ничего не меняет, за исключением выскакивающих ошибок, что алиасы невозможно найти, postfix все также продолжает падать.

Comment: @Magi удалось решить проблему?